# Where should I host my Silverlight videos?

Tags: silverlight, video, video-streaming

I am writing a Silverlight application which displays large applications. It uses MediaElement and the user can scroll to any particular point in the video.

However, I don't want to have to host these large videos myself. What is the easiest/best option for hosting? (A sort of youtube for silverlight if you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about smooth streaming you could put it almost anywhere.

For smooth streaming, you'd probably want a cdn that supports it like limelight http://www.limelightnetworks.com/2010/03/smooth-streaming/ .. Or use something like Amazon S3 or Azure Storage using this technique http://aldenml.com/blog/2009/12/11/how-to-smooth-streaming-and-windows-azure-storage/.

Some cheap hosters like Discountasp.net also support smooth streaming http://www.discountasp.net/sp_iis7manager.aspx

I don't know of any free youtube like places to host the video.  http://silverlight.live.com used to be free, but is shutdown now.